# rspec tests are failing b/c application_controller is making db calls

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have some simple rspec tests that check if a particular page's title is 'xxxx'.

I added some before_filter's to my application_controller which makes db calls.

Should I be mocking these out somehow?

The tests are failing saying "mysql2::error table myapp_test.articles doesn't exist.

Comment: What OS are you running under? I ask, because there's an issue with the MySQL2 gem under Windows where running rake db:test:prepare will actually fail silently on tables with certain column types.

Comment: What does b/c mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds more like you need to run `rake db:test:prepare` or `rake db:migrate db:test:prepare` to me.  Do you have something set up so your rspecs fail when they hit the database intentionally?